# Typescript TSX and generic parameters

Tags: generics, typescript, jsx

Typescript introduces support for the JSX syntax. So I have an expression that works quite well with traditional *.ts files but no with *.tsx ones:

```
const f = <T1>(arg1: T1) => <T2>(arg2: T2) => {
   return { arg1, arg2 };
}
```

I wonder is there a way to make it work inside a *.tsx file?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4922

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To get it to understand it's a type parameter and not a JSX element, you can add a comma after the type parameter:

```
const f = <T1,>(arg1: T1) => <T2,>(arg2: T2) => {
   return { arg1, arg2 };
};
```

Or you could use function expressions instead:

```
const f = function<T1>(arg1: T1) {
    return function<T2>(arg2: T2) {
        return { arg1, arg2 };
    };
};
```

Or alternatively, in this scenario, this works:

```
const f = <T1, T2>(arg1: T1) => (arg2: T2) => {
   return { arg1, arg2 };
};
```

Comment: I've also found that just adding a comma works, which seems to be the best solution for me. It seems like it just hints to TS that this is a generic rather than a JSX element, without actually changing any functionality. There's even been specific prettier updates to allow this particular trailing comma: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/6114

Comment: @Jasper36 yes, that is the recommended way of doing it from my understanding. It was in the answer, but I've moved it to the top now.

Comment: You can also add a type constraint, like `<T extends string>`

Answer (score 54):

This is a result of parsing ambiguity issues. One thing that would make this unambiguous is adding an explicit constraint on `T1`.

```
const f = <T1 extends unknown>(arg1: T1) => {
    return { arg1 };
}
```

Type parameters like `T1` implicitly have a constraint of `unknown` anyway, so in this case your code is functionally equivalent.

Take this solution and you can apply on each arrow function from your original example.

Comment: It should've been `extends any`

Comment: I work on the team and no it shouldn't have. As I explained above, generics without a constraint get an implicit constraint of `{}`, and for the most part are functionally equivalent.

Comment: @DanielRosenwasser I've run into a lot of trouble trying to use `extends {}` because in that case your function wouldn't accept something pretty common like React.ReactNode (which can be null). Are there any gotchas with using <T, Dummy>? So far seems to be working ok but wanted to make sure. This one sounds the cleanest to me, and makes explicit the reason why it's not just T.

Comment: With TypeScript 3.0 you can use `extends unknown` and I think that should work.

Comment: Unfortunately now Eslint reports error  Constraining the generic type `STATE` to `unknown` does nothing and is unnecessary      @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-constraint