# TypeScript: How can I properly type a function that takes a promise and returns that promise as it is

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a function called `prepareOnTick` and it returns a function which takes a promise and adds some logic in the promise's `then` `catch` `finally` callbacks.

```
const prepareOnTick = (onPerItemSettle: OnPerItemSettle) => {
  return (promise: Promise<any>) => {
    promise
      .then(
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onSuccess?.();
        },
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onError?.();
        }
      )
      .finally(() => {
        onPerItemSettle.onSettled?.();
      });

    return promise;
  };
};

const onTick = prepareOnTick({...})
```

I want the type of `onTick` to reflect the fact that whatever promise it takes, it is going to return that as it is. But now the type for it is `(promise: Promise<any>) => Promise<any>` which is not quite accurate. I suppose it should be  `(promise: Promise<T>) => Promise<T>`.

So I tried to type it like this

```
const prepareOnTick = (onPerItemSettle: OnPerItemSettle) => {
  return <T>(promise: Promise<T>):  Promise<T>=> {
    promise
      .then(
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onSuccess?.();
        },
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onError?.();
        }
      )
      .finally(() => {
        onPerItemSettle.onSettled?.();
      });

    return promise;
  };
};
```

But TS compiler doesn't like my type annotations apparently so I must be doing something wrong.
This is the [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIgArQJKQLYDKEYYANigN4BQyyA9iAQK4JIDObA-AFzIBiTEAjDAGAbhr0QAUShQ6UHv0HDRICbQZES5ACZKBQkeKoBfKlQQM2YZAAcoEO3EfoAKsAQBrZAF5kABQMWFC4EITEZBC86CFhEToQAJR%20AHzI1LSOYExQIMgAPG6pAQ50eMBs0cgY8hVVRalJvDV1lRCNvumZtPZtVZK9yAB0YAAWECABg0OBKV0ZM7NScfjaUcNaLOxcwwFJGsvIpgA0S737aYtHvcE4a5HkmzJyCpx7B%20e05stJ58MwUBwUikACeAUuCx6yzuoQeiWe6z0732hyGpk%20M2yuXyZXqEEOpgkRIsVhANikHm8fj6ThcEHcni8AQoWkeEF0vEh6TJbDoT1IdAA5gEAORVRK6UVJDFAA)  can someone take a look at it?

Comment: This is a rather odd thing to do; forming a private branch without terminal error handling and with no means of chaining to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add extra comma after generic parameter, here: `return <T,>`

```js
const prepareOnTick = (onPerItemSettle: OnPerItemSettle) => {
  // TS compiler does not like <T>, he likes more <T,> or <T extends unknown> because of 
  // JSX :D
  return <T,>(promise: Promise<T>):  Promise<T>=> {
    promise
      .then(
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onSuccess?.();
        },
        () => {
          onPerItemSettle.onError?.();
        }
      )
      .finally(() => {
        onPerItemSettle.onSettled?.();
      });

    return promise;
  };
};
```

You should take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32696475/typescript-tsx-and-generic-parameters)